# Creating a multi line echo block in Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, sh

I'm trying to write a simple Makefile for a project with some ascii art as a header but I keep getting errors when I run it. Is there a way to add multiline echo statements instead of @echoing every line? That might not give me errors, something like a `BOF` - `EOF` thing?

What I have is;

```
.PHONY: all

info: header

header:
    clear
    @echo "___________              __   "
    @echo "\__    ___/___   _______/  |_ "
    @echo "  |    |_/ __ \ /  ___/\   __\"
    @echo "  |    |\  ___/ \___ \  |  |  "
    @echo "  |____| \___  >____  > |__|  "
    @echo "             \/     \/        "
```

When I run it, I get the following error;

```
___________              __
\__    ___/___   _______/  |_
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [header] Error 2
```

Comment: `\"` at the end of the third echo should print a quote, and leave the string unclosed, which causes your error. Double the backslash to avoid it.

Comment: ^^ Or use single quotes.

Comment: `.ONESHELL` has existed for a long time by now, I think it's safe to rely on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem comes from the interpretation of `\` characters by the shell. You can escape them by doubling all of them or you can try this, which is maybe a bit simpler:

```
.PHONY: all

info: header

define HEADER
___________              __
\__    ___/___   _______/  |_
  |    |_/ __ \ /  ___/\   __\\
  |    |\  ___/ \___ \  |  |
  |____| \___  >____  > |__|
             \/     \/
endef
export HEADER

header:
    clear
    @echo "$$HEADER"
```

Note: you still need to double the `\` at the end of lines of the text string to avoid that they get interpreted as a line continuation.

Comment: You could also add a space after the `\\` at the end of the line if you don't want a double slash to appear in your output.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry It is in the input that the double backslash appears. In the output it is the expected single backslash. And yes, one could do what you suggest. I personally prefer the visible explicit solution because it is visible and it avoids the risk that somebody else deletes the (apparently useless) space without knowing what the consequences are. Of course, someone could also delete the second backslash, thinking it is useless, but I believe it is less likely.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Have you tried it?   On my make (gnu make 3.81 and 4.2.1), the double backslash at the end of the line appears in the output.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry Yes, I tried it (with GNU make 3.81 and 4.2.1) and it works as I explain. If you see a double backslash on the output it is probably because you left a space after them. Use one or the other method but not both.

Comment: Interesting...  I definitely do not have an extra space at the end of the line, and I'm seeing the double backslash on my output.   I tried setting SHELL to both bash and sh, so I'm not sure what would account for the difference in behavior.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry Interesting, indeed. I'd like to understand. Can you please download [my Makefile](https://www.pacalet.fr/renaud/public/Makefile) and `diff`  it with yours? Note: I ran my tests on macOS 10.13.6 and Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster).

Comment: I ran with your makefile and still got the double slashes at the end of the line.  I'm running linux 2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64.   Is it possible you have dos line endings?   A `cat -e Makefile` on my system shows `  |    |_/ __ \ /  ___/\   __\\$` as the input, and the output is `  |    |_/ __ \ /  ___/\   __\\ ` (syntax highlighting not working in SO for this line -- line ends with double slash, without space at end...)

Comment: @void "Not working" is not really helpful... It works here and now.